# Issues with comparing .ToString()

Tags: c#

so I'm making a mock program just to get somewhat more used to `c#` and heres what i've got:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo Input;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
const string Password = "class";

Console.Write("Input Your Password: ");
    do
    {
        Input = Console.ReadKey(true);
        sb.Append(Input.KeyChar); 
    } while (Input.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    Console.WriteLine();

    if (sb.ToString() == Password)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Correct Password!");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("You Entered: " + sb.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("The Pass is: " + Password);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

But I have an issue with my if-statement when I come to compare `sb.ToString()` and `Password`. Although if you put the same thing in as `Password` the if-statement still doesn't become true.

Why is this?

Comment: You added the Enter key to `sb`, it of course isn't present in "class".  You'll need to do more work, like handing a backspace correctly and deal with an ill-fated attempt by the user when he presses F1 to ask for help :)

Comment: Suggestion: You could also use `Console.ReadLine()` method instead of reading single chars in loop

Comment: Hans Passant's comment is spot-on. Note that you haven't told us the actual contents of `sb`; you've only told us that `sb` contains the same thing as `Password`. But have you actually verified this? Did you stop program execution right before the comparison and inspect the result of `sb.ToString()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are also adding the `Enter` key to `StringBuilder` at the end, you can just check it before adding:

```
do
{
    Input = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if(Input.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
       sb.Append(Input.KeyChar); 
} while (Input.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
```

Or instead of checking it twice you can also refactor your loop like this:

```
while ((Input = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
   sb.Append(Input.KeyChar);
```

Comment: I think this is more readable as an "infinite" loop with a `break;` in the middle: you'd avoid repeating the condition. Alternatively, idiomatic in C and uncommon but valid in C#, move the assignment into the comparison: `while ((Input = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) sb.Append(Input.KeyChar);`.

Comment: @hvd I was just going to suggest same thing :)